# Espresso idling resource never idle with scroll_behavior

Tags: android, android-espresso

Launching my test on an activity with a coordinator layout and nested scrollview with

`layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

set causes the test to never settle.  I've narrowed it down to working and not working with just this line.

Anyone ever dealt with this?

When the layout_behavior is set the Looper logs are overloaded with:

```
Dispatching to Handler (android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler) {8d716a} android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver@6c3c65b: 0

Finished to Handler (android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler) {8d716a} android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver@6c3c65b
```

Comment: fixed by removing app:layout_anchor="@id/myview" from NestedScrollView

Answer (score 1):

fixed by removing app:layout_anchor="@id/myview" from NestedScrollView